# Idiomatic way to check std::chrono duration is less than 0

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I know I can do this

```
if (timeLeft.count() < 0)
```

But I wonder what is the best way since I could also do:

```
if (timeLeft<std::chrono::seconds(0)) // or milliseconds or nanonseconds...
```

note: I assume both checks are the same, but I am not a chrono expert.

edit:full example:

```
#include<chrono>
int main(){
    const std::chrono::nanoseconds timeLeft(-5);
    if(timeLeft<std::chrono::seconds(0)){
        return 47;
    }
}
```

edit2: potential problem with `std::chrono::seconds(0)` is that novice programmer might assume it involves rounding although it does not.

Comment: what exaclty is `timeLeft` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 added full example.

Comment: Usually shorter/simpler is better including IMO in this case, and yes: zero of any chrono duration is zero in the others, but I suspect this is ultimately opinion-based. Personally I would use the shorter/simpler code, and I definitely wouldn't compare `nanoseconds` to `seconds` if there's no need to, so `if (timeLeft.count() < 0)` seems a clear winner to me.

Comment: assuming they are equivalent I'd go for `timeLeft<std::chrono::seconds(0)` because it will be easier to refactor `0` to eg `42`. Btw "are they the same?" isn't opinion-based, but in case they are the same asking "which is better?" is opinion-based. Maybe a little rephrasing can avoid the question from getting closed

Comment: Always prefer to stay within the chrono type system instead of escape it with `.count()` as shown in [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64207194/576911).  And a novice should soon learn that chrono comparisons are *always* exact.  Indeed, everything in chrono is exact until you see an explicit named cast (`duration_cast`, `time_point_cast`, `floor`, `ceil` or `round`).

Comment: @HowardHinnant I know he should, but will he ;) 
But joking aside, I think you are right... in the long run saving him from learning this does more harm than good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways to express this is by using std::chrono::duration literals (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). It's short and clean:

```
#include<chrono>

int main(){
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    
    const auto timeLeft = -5ns;
    if(timeLeft<0s){
        return 47;
    }
}
```